# no space left and weird output of df -kh

Tags: 11.04, wubi

I installed ubuntu 11 in windows vista using wubi. After using it for 3 days, I encountered the problem "No space left in device". The following is the output of "df -kh":

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/loop0            3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /  
none                  1.5G  696K  1.5G   1% /dev  
none                  1.5G  408K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm  
none                  1.5G  100K  1.5G   1% /var/run  
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/lock  
/dev/sda5              40G   15G   26G  37% /host  
/dev/loop1            3.9G  317M  3.4G   9% /home  
/dev/loop2            3.9G  2.6G  1.1G  71% /usr
```

The output of "df -i" is:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on  
/dev/loop0            256000   41900  214100   17% /  
none                  379462     929  378533    1% /dev  
none                  381387      15  381372    1% /dev/shm  
none                  381387      50  381337    1% /var/run  
none                  381387       3  381384    1% /var/lock  
/dev/sda5                  0       0       0    -  /host  
/dev/loop1            256000    2561  253439    2% /home  
/dev/loop2            256000  149893  106107   59% /usr
```

I found that /host/ubuntu/disks occupies 14G. The distribution is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  32K 2011-07-31 21:56 boot  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0G 2011-08-03 10:25 home.disk  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0G 2011-08-03 10:25 root.disk  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 256M 2011-07-31 22:19 swap.disk  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0G 2011-08-03 10:15 usr.disk
```

What's happening? What should I do to increase space? Can I allocate more space to Ubuntu from vista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've installed on a FAT32 partition most likely - which has a *single file size limit* of 4GB. So Wubi splits the install into separate virtual disks of 4GB. You have one for /, /home and /usr

One of these (/) is running out of space (root.disk). There's no way to fix this really - maybe you can clean out your package cache (`sudo apt-get clean`).

It's better to install Wubi on an NTFS partition as then you'll get a single 14GB (or up to 30GB) virtual disk and so you won't have this problem. Or if your FAT32 partition is just for Ubuntu (which it appears it is), then install direct to it (not with Wubi).

Comment: It's weird that I've already used up all 4G space of '/'. how do I find the folder of the largest size under '/'? I did du and only find /host which has .disk files.

Comment: @dalibocai: I tend to use `du -sch /*` which will give summed totals per-directory.

Comment: You can also use the disk usage analyser (baobab). Run it like this: Alt-F2, gksu baobab   (Then STOP it - or it will analyze your /host partition and give confusing results. Go to the Edit/Preferences and uncheck the /host partition, before scanning again)

Comment: @dalibocai 4gb just isn't enough space.  You need to do a proper, non wubi install and give Ubuntu its own partition that is at least 10gb.